# Refresh old cached data in Android

Tags: android, database, caching

I have an Android database table that caches items:

```
@Entity(tableName = "plants")
data class Plant(
    @PrimaryKey val plantId: String,
    val name: String,
    val description: String,
    val category: String,
    val imageUrl: String = ""
)
```

They are loaded externally by `category` - `grass`, `trees`, `bushes` etc. Every day I plan to update my cached data in only categories that used by user. So, for this, I added another timestamp table:

```
@Entity(tableName = "categories_table")
data class CategoryData(
    @PrimaryKey val category: String = "",
    val timestamp: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()
)
```

Every application launch it checks if there needed categories data stored in database and if its `timestamp` differs from the current time less than 1 day. If yes, I proceed with database data, if not - load the data externally and update the database, so my cache is actual for the needed `plant` `categories`. Is there a better way to keep the cache up to date?

Comment: I think your solution is straightforward and correct. There is no need for schedulers and jobs for updates as user may not open the app for days so there is no point in regular checks for that.

Comment: Thanks. I think, modern phones are quite productive, so some easy calculations and caching should be on them to decrease network and backend usage. But in my solution there is an extra table created, so I need to make 3 extra classes: data class, DAO, repository, then add an extra observer/transformation and merge the data in both tables. It's nice to have a simpler solution if possible, like if there a special database mechanism already included.

Comment: I think it is pretty "normal" need to create DAO and repo and data classes. You can look into the table linking and having the foreign key to Improve that part